# How can I make a generic extension in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want make a generic extension for avoiding me to repeating my code for deferent types. here is my code need to get fixed!

```
    extension Bool {
    
    func print() { Swift.print(self.description) }
    
}

extension Int {
    
    func print() { Swift.print(self.description) }
    
}

extension String {
    
    func print() { Swift.print(self.description) }
    
}
```

---

```
 extension <T> {
    
    func print() { Swift.print(self.description) }
    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your extension is not "generic" in the sense that it can apply to *any* type. It can only apply to types that have a `description` property. Well, which types have a `description` property? Every type that conforms to [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible) does!

So you should create an extension of `CustomStringConvertible`:

```
extension CustomStringConvertible {
    
    func print() { Swift.print(self.description) }
    
}
```

<sub>(Note that there could be a type that have a `description` property, but does not conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, but most types in the standard libraries aren't like this)</sub>

Truly generic extensions are [something else](https://forums.swift.org/t/parameterized-extensions/25563), and is currently being proposed, i.e. not part of Swift yet.

Comment: I have a small question here, if I want make my custom print() be workable on custom type, should I work on extension of CustomStringConvertible, I think?

Comment: @mimi You should make your custom type conform to `CustomStringConvertible`. e.g. `class CustomType: CustomStringConvertible { var description: String { ... } }`

Comment: aha! so my custom type should describe "var description" to be conforming CustomStringConvertible! thanks